# Restrict Google Maps from automatically opening in Mobile Application

Tags: android, html, cordova, google-maps

I am developing a mobile application using PhoneGap / Cordova, and have embedded maps in certain parts of the application to display location to the user. However, when the application is opened, all the maps on the app initialise simultaneously. This causes major performance lag on the app, as well as eats alot of data.

A button is used to open each specific part of the app, and the maps are embedded in these containers. Is there a way to restrict the maps from initialising until a button is clicked?

Your help is greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, your problem is based in how your views are rendered, and the design pattern of your application. In some frameworks, the views are rendered only when they are invoqued, another save the data in cache, or all are rendered.

Maybe your problem is only in the part that you are initializing the maps, so you only have to move the initialization to the moment that you display that concrete view, but you should look at some frameworks to learn about views, memory and cache management.